# Switch statement to IF/while

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering how could I write the following code only with IF, WHILE or FOR (without switch/case statements)?

```
if(ulDataBuf!=15 && ulData==15)
{
  switch(ulDataBuf){
  case 14:
      timeON+=500000;
      break;
  case 13:
      if(timeON!=0) timeON-=500000;
      break;
  case 11:
      timeOFF+=500000;
      break;
  case 7:
      if(timeOFF!=0) timeOFF-=500000;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to?

Comment: Practically every tutorial on `switch`es starts with how you can fold multiple `if`-`else if`s into a `switch`, surely reversing that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Paul: I just couldn't get it to work properly :\

Comment: @Kninnug: You got any good links to tutorials?

Comment: @MemFaction: Well, post what you tried, and let's take a look at it. There are a billion different ways in which it might not work, we can't guess which one of those ways you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(ulDataBuf!=15 && ulData==15)
{
    if(ulDatabuf == 14)
    {
        timeON+=500000;
    }
    else if(ulDatabuf == 13)
    {
        if(timeON!=0)
        {
            timeON-=500000; 
        }
    }
    else if(ulDatabuf == 11)
    {
        timeOFF+=500000;
    }
    else if(ulDatabuf == 7)
    {
        if(timeOFF!=0)
        {
        timeOFF-=500000;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Perhaps you might know even that one, here's the code:
`up=0;
      if(ulData==button_up){               
        if(up==0){
        delay_on=delay_on+100000;       
        up=1;}                         
        ulData=GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTE_BASE,(GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3));  
      }`

As you can see, program needs to wait until button up is pressed, which is solved with while loop. Any ideas to make that work only with "if", "switch-case", or something similar? While loop, delays and timers are not allowed :\

Answer (score 2):

Basically replace the first case with an if-statement and the rest of the cases with an if-else-statement. You will have a structure like below:

```
if ( if(ulDataBuf!=15 && ulData==15) ) {
    if ( 14 == ulDataBuf ) {
        timeON+=500000;
    } else if ( 13 == ulDataBuf ) {
        if(timeON!=0) timeON-=500000;
    }
}
```

And so on...

Comment: Thank you very much!
Perhaps you might know even that one, here's the code:
`up=0;
      if(ulData==button_up){               
        if(up==0){
        delay_on=delay_on+100000;       
        up=1;}                         
        ulData=GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTE_BASE,(GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3));  
      }`

As you can see, program needs to wait until button up is pressed, which is solved with while loop. Any ideas to make that work only with "if", "switch-case", or something similar? While loop, delays and timers are not allowed :\

Comment: Check the following article: http://www.cosmiacpubs.org/pubs/uC_Lab5.pdf. Check page 6, there you'll find information about interrupts. I think that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers answer your question perfectly - but I have my own question: why would you want to do this? Usually when compiled switch statements boil down to jump tables in assembler whilst multiple if-else branches can make the amount of generated instructions increase.

Comment: This is best suited as a comment...